# Why does EF Core 7 always translate my datetime where clause to '0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000'

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I'm pretty sure I've done this in EF Core 6 and it worked before, but now I've upgraded to EF Core 7 and my datetime values are being translated to '0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000'
For example:

```
Console.Write("DateFrom:");
Console.WriteLine(dateFrom);
query = query.Where(e => e.TIME_START >= dateFrom);
var count = await query.CountAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

produces this in the console:

```
DateFrom:1/30/2023 12:00:00 AM
[10:15:11 INF] Executed DbCommand (19ms) [Parameters=[@__dateFrom_0='0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [reports].[RPT_RUN] AS [r]
WHERE [r].[SUCCESS] = CAST(1 AS bit) AND [r].[TIME_START] >= @__dateFrom_0
```

I am under the impression that this comparison in the where clause should this work?

Comment: What is the type of the `TIME_START` property? Also what is the type of the target database provider (Npgsql?)

Comment: TIME_START is DateTime on the POCO, and DATETIME2(7) in the SQL Server DB.

Comment: So I changed the SQL Column to DateTime to see what happens.
I added this to the model configuration: entity.Property(e => e.TIME_START).HasColumnType("datetime");
The value for TIME_START in the db = '2023-01-28 08:12:04.423'
When I run the same query I get this error:
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Comment: Too bad. That means EF Core still sends empty `DateTime` value via `SqlParameter`.  Honestly have no idea, first time seeing something like this. Could you provide a minimal repro?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but it works fine if a move the DbContext code to a brand-new project. Seems like something in my existing project is causing the issue.